# Did sharing a link on Facebook with multiple images via graph-api break about a week ago?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have pages on my web site with graph-api tags such as the following:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The NERAIL New England Railroad Photo Archive" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://photos.nerail.org/show/?order=byday&page=1&key=20170919&key2=" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000099244726" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="New photos for September 19, 2017." />
<meta property="og:description" content="12 new railroad photographs for your enjoyment!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.nerail.org/photos/2017/09/19/201709192207547979.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="850" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="567" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.nerail.org/photos/2017/09/19/2017091917343423937.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="850" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="567" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.nerail.org/photos/2017/09/19/2017091917314323493.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="850" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="567" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.nerail.org/photos/2017/09/19/2017091917280423369.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="850" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="567" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.nerail.org/photos/2017/09/19/2017091917245523309.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="850" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="478" />
```

As you can see, I'm specifying up to five images for the page.

Up until about 9/19/2017, when I pasted a link to one of my page into a Facebook post (the Facebook web site that is, not the mobile app), Facebook would show me previews of the five images, and allow me to pick one or more of them to display with the post. If I picked only one, it would use the image I picked in the post. If I picked more than one, it would display all of them with arrows, allowing the person viewing the post to scroll through them.

Normally when sharing links to my pages, I would pick which photo I liked the best and use this for my post. This was the behavior I wanted and why I added the open graph tags to my pages in the first place, and how it has been working since I did so several years ago.

Now though, starting around 9/19/2017, if I try to select only one image, Facebook forces it to be the first image. In other words, it shows me the five preview images, but if I unselect all but one of them, regardless of which one I try to leave selected, Facebook highlights and uses the first one.

This behavior feels very much like a Facebook bug, but of course Facebook provides no way to contact them or report bugs. :-( This has stopped me dead in my tracks from publishing links to my pages, which I used to do for my users every single day. I can't simply use the first image all the time, because I have multiple pages that would all show up with the same image if I did that. Plus I like to choose the "best" image for my post.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is it something wrong with my open graph tags? Again, it's been working for years, but perhaps there's been something wrong with my tags all along and Facebook just "fixed" something? Should I be including some sort of index for my image tags to tell Facebook what order they should be in? I can't find anything in the Facebook developer apps describing a way to do so. In their examples they simply show multiple image tags, as I have in my example above.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not an issue of the tags, I think. That you can specify multiple images this way is even “officially” documented under http://ogp.me/ What Facebook _makes_ of them however is not documented anywhere - so you could say, that it did work the way you wanted it to up til now, was more of a “courtesy” feature ... If they deliberately removed this now, it might be part of the set of measures to help fighting fake news.

Comment: As for reporting bugs - the Help section has a form to report “broken features”. Since this concerns OG meta tags, one might also consider it a bug relevant to developers, so you could try and report it via the official bug tracker as well.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I tried filing a bug report through the developers bug tracker. They closed it, saying it was a Facebook issue, not an API issue, and directed me to the "broken features" form you mentioned. Unfortunately the broken features form simply results in a generic "thanks for your feedback, we can't respond to individual reports" canned response, thus my comment about there being no way to get traction from them on this. I should have been more specific. They're completely uninterested in helping/don't care about their users. (I know, surprise, surprise, it's Facebook.) :-(